# SQL Query Throws Exception When Run From IIS Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I built a simple ASP.NET web app using Web Forms. On the default page, a button click was used to run a SQL query, the output of which was added to three list boxes. the source code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication3
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=WebApp;" +
                                    "password=[REMOVED];" + 
                                    "server=JC-SRV;" +
                                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                    "database=Database; " +
                                    "connection timeout=30");

        string Command = ("SELECT *" + "FROM Table");


        try
        {
            TextBox4.Text = ("Attempting to connect to database...");
            myConnection.Open();
            TextBox4.Text = ("Success!");
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, myConnection);
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add("Field 1 " + myReader["Test1"].ToString());
                    ListBox2.Items.Add("Field 2 " + myReader["Test2"].ToString());
                    ListBox3.Items.Add("Field 3 " + myReader["Test3"].ToString());

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TextBox4.Text = (ex.ToString());

            }

            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TextBox4.Text = (ex.ToString());

        }
    }
    }
}
```

This works fine when run from my development machine in Visual Studio 2013 and IIS Express, however, when I publish the project to my Server 2008 R2 box with IIS 7.0 installed the following exception is thrown:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
>   'CHARMAN\JC-SRV$'.   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()   at
>   WebApplication3._Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e)ClientConnectionId:0516c418-145d-4558-b9d7-ed2e55c74724

It may be worth noting that the server is a DC of a domain called CHARMAN and that JC-SRV is the machine name. The SQL 2014 server is running on this machine also.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is pretty strait forward..The machine in question in not allowed to login in the data base.

Comment: When I use Trusted_Connection, I'm assuming windows authentication from the context my app is running.  In my case it's usually the running user of the application pool of my site.  In these cases, I've never had a username and password in the connection string.  It looks like you may want sql authentication instead?

Comment: @Andre I can access the the database using those credentials from SMSS and the same machine... How would this be different when the app is in a web server?

Comment: @JasonEades I removed trusted_connection and still get the same error. The ID and password are for SQL authentication. What would you suggest?

Comment: Try something like this as your connection string: Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User Id=blah;Password=blah;

Comment: @JasonEades Same exception gets thrown...

Comment: @JakeCharman Same exactly?  The stack trace looks like login failed for a domain user rather than a sql account.

Comment: @JasonEades My apologies.. the new exception is too long for a comment but begins System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) --- –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415319/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user) I added

```
Integrated Security=False
```

To the connection string and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Contact your DBA and get the required permissions for "CHARMAN\JC-SRV$" on the SQL Server instance in question.

Note: I don't have privileges to add comments hence posting my comment as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am just playing around in my own network at home. Therefore there is nobody to contact.

Comment: If you have SA role then provide Public role to this user on the databases you need to connect  from security. (Atleast Public role. )