# sql network interfaces error 26 - error locating server/instance specified

Tags: sql-server, database, management-studio-express

Okay so a lot of people have posted a similar question, however I don't seem to be able to find a solution to my problem in any of them. So this is my situation.

Yesterday I was working with my SQL Server Express through SQL Server Management Studio. I close my projects as I've done multiple times before and then this morning when I tried to connect again with the tool is gives me this error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to .\SQLExpress.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

I think my main question here is if there is a solution to this problem, or if I have to install SQL Server Express all over again?

PS: Here are some system stats. I'm working on a Windows 10 machine, and the SQL Server Management Studio version is 2014.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: @Jonathan: It worked. Can you possibly make an answer, in order for me to tig this as solved?

Comment: sure @michael i will frame and post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Click on `SQL Server Network Configuration` and click on `Protocols for Name`
3. Right click on `TCP/IP` (make sure it is Enabled), click on `Properties`
4. Select `IP Addresses` Tab and go to the last entry: `IP All`
5. Enter `TCP Port 1433`.

Now restart "SQL Server .Name." using `services.msc` (winKey + r)

Comment: And if that doesn't work, on Windows 10 it could be [the firewall, and you will also have to do this](https://superuser.com/q/1303512/297822).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but a different solution. My protocols was configured correctly but I was still getting the problem. In *SQL Server Configuration Manager* make sure that the *SQL Server Browser* is configured to start automatically and is running. As soon as the service was active my problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

this issue also confusing me a few days after the IT guy do some security settings to the SQL Server. i have an EntityFramework for the Web application and a desktop application. after i did some setting on the SQL Server, the Web application comeback to work, but the desktop still with issue. but i used the some connection string for the both application, it make no sense one is work but the other doesn't. then i searched a lot until i found some one said need add a port number 1433 after the **$ServerName$DatabaseInstanceName,1433** at here http://www.windows-tech.info/15/9f6dedc097727100.php . after i added it. the exception became: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'domain\name-PC$'. then i found this link [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415319/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user/70587402#70587402) : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user it said need add **Trusted_Connection=False;**. the whole connection string should be like: *data source=XXXXX\SQLSERVER,1433;initial catalog=XXXDB;user id=UserID;password=PWD;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;*

hope this answer will help the ones out off Generic exception: "Error: 26-Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)