# Login failed for user 'XX'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Login failed for user 'xx'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'xx

Comment: `Login failed for user 'xx'` Once login successes, then the error will be gone. Please check your connection string `User name` and `password` and `Server Name` and `Database Name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415319/system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-user)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved after changing the settings of IIS. I have changed it to Application pools--> Default app pool --> advance settings--> identity --> local system.[IIS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPeJD.png)
. Also i have changed the settings on SQL database(security --> logins-->select your login name --> (right click )properties-->server role--> sysadmin) [Database settings on login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzYCD.png)